# New set up DHCP Server on Server 2008 R2 won't work, Event-ID 1046

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, dhcp, domain-controller, windows-event-log

I just set up a 2008 R2 as DC, and DNS. Both worked fine, DNS works fine forward and reverse lookup.

Now I wanted to install DHCP. As soon as the installation of the role is finished, I get this Event-ID Error 1046: [Link](http://www.eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=1046&eventno=2944&source=DhcpServer&phase=1)

When I first set it up there was also a Event-ID 1059 Error: [Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc774849%28WS.10%29.aspx)

The dhcp server is authorized. I don't know what else I should do. Getting crazy here, hope you guys can help me.

Comment: and I assume its not handing out ip addresses correct? On the dhcp server do a nslookup fqdn of the domain as in companyname.com or maybe sub.companyname.com etc...

Answer (score 2):

[You need to authorize DHCP servers that are part of an AD domain.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759688(v=ws.10).aspx) This prevents unauthorized DHCP servers from starting on your network.

To authorize the server, from the DCHP console, right click on the DHCP server and select Authorize Server. You have to be logged in as a member of the Domain Admins or DHCP Admins group to do this.

Answer (score -1):

Try some of these: http://www.eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=1059&eventno=3795&source=DhcpServer&phase=1

Look at the DNS configuration and check wheater your primary DNS server is Domain Controllers ip address.